# No inicia el service

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

Esta clase intenta pasar un intent con un ArrayList y un int a un Service para que este haga cierto proceso e inicia una nueva activity.

```
 public void battleFinal(View view){
    Intent prueba = new Intent(this, serviceName.class);
    prueba.putExtra("lista",itemList);
    prueba.putExtra("segundos",secTotal);
    startService(prueba);

  

    Intent battleFinal = new Intent(this, disputa_nombres.class);
    battleFinal.putExtra("lista",itemList);
    battleFinal.putExtra("segundos",secTotal);
   // startService(battleFinal);
    startActivity(battleFinal);


}
```

Esta segunda es el servicio en cuestión

```
public class serviceName extends Service {
private ArrayList<String> itemList ;
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     itemList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("lista");
    System.out.println(itemList);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
```

}

La primera clase es de clase activity y la segunda extiende de Service por eso creo que el startService no funciona, pero necesito pasarle al servicio la información recogida en la activity por el usuario ¿Es posible hacerlo así o como se puede hacer? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Recuerda siempre revisar el LogCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es importante que declares dentro de tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml el poder ejecutar el servicio, de otra forma este no podrá iniciar:

```
<manifest ... >
  ...
  <application ... >
      <service android:name=".ExampleService" />
      ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Revisa la documentación:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Dentro de onStartCommand() siempre estas esperando recibir un Intent, en este caso te sugiero validar :

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       
    if(intent != null){
       itemList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("lista");
       System.out.println(itemList);
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```